# Jinja2 remove blank line before data

Tags: python, jinja2

I render template that looks like this

```
template = jinja2.Template('''
{%- for item in data -%}
...
{%- endfor -%}
''')
```

And though I put '-' I have blank line before the cycle.

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: I don't have much Jinja experience, but it might be because you've started the triple-quoted string on the line before the loop, meaning the first character would be a newline.

Comment: @CrunchyBox I tried that, no result

Comment: I wonder if your ‘item’ has a newline before the string, rather than after the string as you expect. What does your data/item object look like?

Comment: My experience with Jinja is that you really can't get rid of the blank lines that it likes to put everywhere.  I just filtered my output and deleted them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the result of render is str I decided to strip it. That's the only thing that works